# Why did I get hardcoded value?

Tags: corda

Here is part of my code in build.gradle.

```
...
task deployNodes(type: net.corda.plugins.Cordform, dependsOn: ['jar']) {
    directory "./build/nodes"
    node {
        name "O=Notary,L=London,C=GB"
        notary = [validating : true]
        p2pPort 10002
        rpcSettings {
            address("localhost:10003")
            adminAddress("localhost:10043")
        }
        cordapps = ["$corda_release_group:corda-finance:$corda_release_version"]
    }
    node {
        name "O=PartyA,L=Tokyo,C=JP"
        p2pPort 10005
        rpcSettings {
            address("localhost:10006")
            adminAddress("localhost:10046")
        }
        webPort 10007
        cordapps = ["$corda_release_group:corda-finance:$corda_release_version"]
        rpcUsers = [[user: "user1", "password": "test", "permissions": ["ALL"]]]
    }
    node {
        name "O=PartyB,L=New York,C=US"
        p2pPort 10008
        rpcSettings {
            address("localhost:10009")
            adminAddress("localhost:10049")
        }
        webPort 10010
        sshdPort 10024
        cordapps = ["$corda_release_group:corda-finance:$corda_release_version"]
        rpcUsers = [[user: "user1", "password": "test", "permissions": ["ALL"]]]
    }
...
```

---

When I built and run the node from IntelliJ, I could see the logs.

```
...
2018-04-16 20:37:21,775 main WARN Unable to instantiate org.fusesource.jansi.WindowsAnsiOutputStream
2018-04-16 20:37:21,780 main WARN Unable to instantiate org.fusesource.jansi.WindowsAnsiOutputStream
[INFO ] 20:37:29,586 [driver-pool-thread-0] (ConfigUtilities.kt:38) config.ConfigHelper.loadConfig - Config:
{
    # reference.conf @ jar:file:/C:/Users/XXXXX/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/net.corda/corda-node/3.1-corda/d885cb735f9d9e70dc630587cc5df98c9740f8df/corda-node-3.1-corda.jar!/reference.conf: 20
    "activeMQServer" : {
        # reference.conf @ jar:file:/C:/Users/XXXXX/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/net.corda/corda-node/3.1-corda/d885cb735f9d9e70dc630587cc5df98c9740f8df/corda-node-3.1-corda.jar!/reference.conf: 21
        "bridge" : {
            # reference.conf @ jar:file:/C:/Users/XXXXX/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/net.corda/corda-node/3.1-corda/d885cb735f9d9e70dc630587cc5df98c9740f8df/corda-node-3.1-corda.jar!/reference.conf: 24
            "maxRetryIntervalMin" : 3,
            # reference.conf @ jar:file:/C:/Users/XXXXX/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/net.corda/corda-node/3.1-corda/d885cb735f9d9e70dc630587cc5df98c9740f8df/corda-node-3.1-corda.jar!/reference.conf: 22
            "retryIntervalMs" : 5000,
            # reference.conf @ jar:file:/C:/Users/XXXXX/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/net.corda/corda-node/3.1-corda/d885cb735f9d9e70dc630587cc5df98c9740f8df/corda-node-3.1-corda.jar!/reference.conf: 23
            "retryIntervalMultiplier" : 1.5
        }
    },
    # hardcoded value
    "baseDirectory" : "C:\\work\\corda\\cordapp-example\\build\\20180416-113719.630\\NotaryService",
    # merge of reference.conf @ jar:file:/C:/Users/XXXXX/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/net.corda/corda-node/3.1-corda/d885cb735f9d9e70dc630587cc5df98c9740f8df/corda-node-3.1-corda.jar!/reference.conf: 6,reference.conf @ jar:file:/C:/Users/XXXXX/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/net.corda/corda/3.1-corda/c56c8389dd277cf2a9751f6c9510d1a9f85da47e/corda-3.1-corda.jar!/reference.conf: 6,reference.conf @ jar:file:/C:/Users/XXXXX/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/net.corda/corda-webserver/3.1-corda/f927e48482062fff3761bf293ce5ab2e3191e542/corda-webserver-3.1-corda.jar!/reference.conf: 6
    "dataSourceProperties" : {
        # reference.conf @ jar:file:/C:/Users/XXXXX/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/net.corda/corda-node/3.1-corda/d885cb735f9d9e70dc630587cc5df98c9740f8df/corda-node-3.1-corda.jar!/reference.conf: 10
        "dataSource.password" : "",
        # merge of reference.conf @ jar:file:/C:/Users/XXXXX/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/net.corda/corda-node/3.1-corda/d885cb735f9d9e70dc630587cc5df98c9740f8df/corda-node-3.1-corda.jar!/reference.conf: 8,hardcoded value,reference.conf @ jar:file:/C:/Users/XXXXX/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/net.corda/corda-node/3.1-corda/d885cb735f9d9e70dc630587cc5df98c9740f8df/corda-node-3.1-corda.jar!/reference.conf: 8,reference.conf @ jar:file:/C:/Users/XXXXX/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/net.corda/corda-node/3.1-corda/d885cb735f9d9e70dc630587cc5df98c9740f8df/corda-node-3.1-corda.jar!/reference.conf: 17
        "dataSource.url" : "jdbc:h2:file:C:\\work\\corda\\cordapp-example\\build\\20180416-113719.630\\NotaryService/persistence;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000;WRITE_DELAY=100;AUTO_SERVER_PORT=0",
        # reference.conf @ jar:file:/C:/Users/XXXXX/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/net.corda/corda-node/3.1-corda/d885cb735f9d9e70dc630587cc5df98c9740f8df/corda-node-3.1-corda.jar!/reference.conf: 9
        "dataSource.user" : "sa",
        # reference.conf @ jar:file:/C:/Users/XXXXX/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/net.corda/corda-node/3.1-corda/d885cb735f9d9e70dc630587cc5df98c9740f8df/corda-node-3.1-corda.jar!/reference.conf: 7
        "dataSourceClassName" : "org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource"
    },
    # reference.conf @ jar:file:/C:/Users/XXXXX/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/net.corda/corda-node/3.1-corda/d885cb735f9d9e70dc630587cc5df98c9740f8df/corda-node-3.1-corda.jar!/reference.conf: 12
    "database" : {
        # reference.conf @ jar:file:/C:/Users/XXXXX/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/net.corda/corda-node/3.1-corda/d885cb735f9d9e70dc630587cc5df98c9740f8df/corda-node-3.1-corda.jar!/reference.conf: 14
        "exportHibernateJMXStatistics" : "false",
        # reference.conf @ jar:file:/C:/Users/XXXXX/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/net.corda/corda-node/3.1-corda/d885cb735f9d9e70dc630587cc5df98c9740f8df/corda-node-3.1-corda.jar!/reference.conf: 13
        "transactionIsolationLevel" : "REPEATABLE_READ"
    },
    # reference.conf @ jar:file:/C:/Users/XXXXX/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/net.corda/corda-node/3.1-corda/d885cb735f9d9e70dc630587cc5df98c9740f8df/corda-node-3.1-corda.jar!/reference.conf: 16
    "devMode" : true,
    # reference.conf @ jar:file:/C:/Users/XXXXX/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/net.corda/corda-node/3.1-corda/d885cb735f9d9e70dc630587cc5df98c9740f8df/corda-node-3.1-corda.jar!/reference.conf: 2
    "emailAddress" : "admin@company.com",
    # reference.conf @ jar:file:/C:/Users/XXXXX/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/net.corda/corda-node/3.1-corda/d885cb735f9d9e70dc630587cc5df98c9740f8df/corda-node-3.1-corda.jar!/reference.conf: 3
    "exportJMXto" : "http",
    # reference.conf @ jar:file:/C:/Users/XXXXX/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/net.corda/corda-node/3.1-corda/d885cb735f9d9e70dc630587cc5df98c9740f8df/corda-node-3.1-corda.jar!/reference.conf: 17
    "h2port" : 0,
    # reference.conf @ jar:file:/C:/Users/XXXXX/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/net.corda/corda-node/3.1-corda/d885cb735f9d9e70dc630587cc5df98c9740f8df/corda-node-3.1-corda.jar!/reference.conf: 4
    "keyStorePassword" : "cordacadevpass",
    # hardcoded value
    "myLegalName" : "O=Notary Service, L=Zurich, C=CH",
    # hardcoded value
    "notary" : {
        # hardcoded value
        "custom" : false,
        # hardcoded value
        "validating" : true
    },
    # hardcoded value
    "p2pAddress" : "localhost:10002",
    # merge of hardcoded value,reference.conf @ jar:file:/C:/Users/XXXXX/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/net.corda/corda-node/3.1-corda/d885cb735f9d9e70dc630587cc5df98c9740f8df/corda-node-3.1-corda.jar!/reference.conf: 27
    "rpcSettings" : {
        # hardcoded value
        "address" : "localhost:10003",
        # hardcoded value
        "adminAddress" : "localhost:10004",
        # reference.conf @ jar:file:/C:/Users/XXXXX/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/net.corda/corda-node/3.1-corda/d885cb735f9d9e70dc630587cc5df98c9740f8df/corda-node-3.1-corda.jar!/reference.conf: 29
        "standAloneBroker" : false,
        # reference.conf @ jar:file:/C:/Users/XXXXX/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/net.corda/corda-node/3.1-corda/d885cb735f9d9e70dc630587cc5df98c9740f8df/corda-node-3.1-corda.jar!/reference.conf: 28
        "useSsl" : false
    },
    # hardcoded value
    "rpcUsers" : [
        # hardcoded value
        {
            # hardcoded value
            "password" : "default",
            # hardcoded value
            "permissions" : [
                # hardcoded value
                "ALL"
            ],
            # hardcoded value
            "username" : "default"
        }
    ],
    # reference.conf @ jar:file:/C:/Users/XXXXX/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/net.corda/corda-node/3.1-corda/d885cb735f9d9e70dc630587cc5df98c9740f8df/corda-node-3.1-corda.jar!/reference.conf: 5
    "trustStorePassword" : "trustpass",
    # hardcoded value
    "useTestClock" : false,
    # hardcoded value
    "verifierType" : "InMemory",
    # hardcoded value
    "webAddress" : "localhost:10005"
}
 {}
[INFO ] 20:37:29,673 [driver-pool-thread-0] (NodeInfoFilesCopier.kt:63) network.NodeInfoFilesCopier.addConfig - Now watching: C:\work\corda\cordapp-example\build\20180416-113719.630\NotaryService {}
[INFO ] 20:37:29,677 [driver-pool-thread-0] (DriverDSLImpl.kt:814) internal.DriverDSLImpl.startOutOfProcessNode - Starting out-of-process Node Notary Service, debug port is 5005, jolokia monitoring port is not enabled {}
[INFO ] 20:37:29,829 [driver-pool-thread-0] (ConfigUtilities.kt:38) config.ConfigHelper.loadConfig - Config:
{
    # reference.conf @ jar:file:/C:/Users/XXXXX/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/net.corda/corda-node/3.1-corda/d885cb735f9d9e70dc630587cc5df98c9740f8df/corda-node-3.1-corda.jar!/reference.conf: 20
    "activeMQServer" : {
        # reference.conf @ jar:file:/C:/Users/XXXXX/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/net.corda/corda-node/3.1-corda/d885cb735f9d9e70dc630587cc5df98c9740f8df/corda-node-3.1-corda.jar!/reference.conf: 21
        "bridge" : {
            # reference.conf @ jar:file:/C:/Users/XXXXX/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/net.corda/corda-node/3.1-corda/d885cb735f9d9e70dc630587cc5df98c9740f8df/corda-node-3.1-corda.jar!/reference.conf: 24
            "maxRetryIntervalMin" : 3,
            # reference.conf @ jar:file:/C:/Users/XXXXX/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/net.corda/corda-node/3.1-corda/d885cb735f9d9e70dc630587cc5df98c9740f8df/corda-node-3.1-corda.jar!/reference.conf: 22
            "retryIntervalMs" : 5000,
            # reference.conf @ jar:file:/C:/Users/XXXXX/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/net.corda/corda-node/3.1-corda/d885cb735f9d9e70dc630587cc5df98c9740f8df/corda-node-3.1-corda.jar!/reference.conf: 23
            "retryIntervalMultiplier" : 1.5
        }
    },
    # hardcoded value
    "baseDirectory" : "C:\\work\\corda\\cordapp-example\\build\\20180416-113719.630\\PartyB",
    # merge of reference.conf @ jar:file:/C:/Users/XXXXX/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/net.corda/corda-node/3.1-corda/d885cb735f9d9e70dc630587cc5df98c9740f8df/corda-node-3.1-corda.jar!/reference.conf: 6,reference.conf @ jar:file:/C:/Users/XXXXX/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/net.corda/corda/3.1-corda/c56c8389dd277cf2a9751f6c9510d1a9f85da47e/corda-3.1-corda.jar!/reference.conf: 6,reference.conf @ jar:file:/C:/Users/XXXXX/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/net.corda/corda-webserver/3.1-corda/f927e48482062fff3761bf293ce5ab2e3191e542/corda-webserver-3.1-corda.jar!/reference.conf: 6
    "dataSourceProperties" : {
        # reference.conf @ jar:file:/C:/Users/XXXXX/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/net.corda/corda-node/3.1-corda/d885cb735f9d9e70dc630587cc5df98c9740f8df/corda-node-3.1-corda.jar!/reference.conf: 10
        "dataSource.password" : "",
        # merge of reference.conf @ jar:file:/C:/Users/XXXXX/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/net.corda/corda-node/3.1-corda/d885cb735f9d9e70dc630587cc5df98c9740f8df/corda-node-3.1-corda.jar!/reference.conf: 8,hardcoded value,reference.conf @ jar:file:/C:/Users/XXXXX/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/net.corda/corda-node/3.1-corda/d885cb735f9d9e70dc630587cc5df98c9740f8df/corda-node-3.1-corda.jar!/reference.conf: 8,reference.conf @ jar:file:/C:/Users/XXXXX/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/net.corda/corda-node/3.1-corda/d885cb735f9d9e70dc630587cc5df98c9740f8df/corda-node-3.1-corda.jar!/reference.conf: 17
        "dataSource.url" : "jdbc:h2:file:C:\\work\\corda\\cordapp-example\\build\\20180416-113719.630\\PartyB/persistence;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000;WRITE_DELAY=100;AUTO_SERVER_PORT=0",
        # reference.conf @ jar:file:/C:/Users/XXXXX/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/net.corda/corda-node/3.1-corda/d885cb735f9d9e70dc630587cc5df98c9740f8df/corda-node-3.1-corda.jar!/reference.conf: 9
        "dataSource.user" : "sa",
        # reference.conf @ jar:file:/C:/Users/XXXXX/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/net.corda/corda-node/3.1-corda/d885cb735f9d9e70dc630587cc5df98c9740f8df/corda-node-3.1-corda.jar!/reference.conf: 7
        "dataSourceClassName" : "org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource"
    },
    # reference.conf @ jar:file:/C:/Users/XXXXX/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/net.corda/corda-node/3.1-corda/d885cb735f9d9e70dc630587cc5df98c9740f8df/corda-node-3.1-corda.jar!/reference.conf: 12
    "database" : {
        # reference.conf @ jar:file:/C:/Users/XXXXX/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/net.corda/corda-node/3.1-corda/d885cb735f9d9e70dc630587cc5df98c9740f8df/corda-node-3.1-corda.jar!/reference.conf: 14
        "exportHibernateJMXStatistics" : "false",
        # reference.conf @ jar:file:/C:/Users/XXXXX/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/net.corda/corda-node/3.1-corda/d885cb735f9d9e70dc630587cc5df98c9740f8df/corda-node-3.1-corda.jar!/reference.conf: 13
        "transactionIsolationLevel" : "REPEATABLE_READ"
    },
    # reference.conf @ jar:file:/C:/Users/XXXXX/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/net.corda/corda-node/3.1-corda/d885cb735f9d9e70dc630587cc5df98c9740f8df/corda-node-3.1-corda.jar!/reference.conf: 16
    "devMode" : true,
    # reference.conf @ jar:file:/C:/Users/XXXXX/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/net.corda/corda-node/3.1-corda/d885cb735f9d9e70dc630587cc5df98c9740f8df/corda-node-3.1-corda.jar!/reference.conf: 2
    "emailAddress" : "admin@company.com",
    # reference.conf @ jar:file:/C:/Users/XXXXX/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/net.corda/corda-node/3.1-corda/d885cb735f9d9e70dc630587cc5df98c9740f8df/corda-node-3.1-corda.jar!/reference.conf: 3
    "exportJMXto" : "http",
    # reference.conf @ jar:file:/C:/Users/XXXXX/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/net.corda/corda-node/3.1-corda/d885cb735f9d9e70dc630587cc5df98c9740f8df/corda-node-3.1-corda.jar!/reference.conf: 17
    "h2port" : 0,
    # reference.conf @ jar:file:/C:/Users/XXXXX/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/net.corda/corda-node/3.1-corda/d885cb735f9d9e70dc630587cc5df98c9740f8df/corda-node-3.1-corda.jar!/reference.conf: 4
    "keyStorePassword" : "cordacadevpass",
    # hardcoded value
    "myLegalName" : "O=PartyB, L=New York, C=US",
    # hardcoded value
    "p2pAddress" : "localhost:10001",
    # merge of hardcoded value,reference.conf @ jar:file:/C:/Users/XXXXX/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/net.corda/corda-node/3.1-corda/d885cb735f9d9e70dc630587cc5df98c9740f8df/corda-node-3.1-corda.jar!/reference.conf: 27
    "rpcSettings" : {
        # hardcoded value
        "address" : "localhost:10006",
        # hardcoded value
        "adminAddress" : "localhost:10007",
        # reference.conf @ jar:file:/C:/Users/XXXXX/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/net.corda/corda-node/3.1-corda/d885cb735f9d9e70dc630587cc5df98c9740f8df/corda-node-3.1-corda.jar!/reference.conf: 29
        "standAloneBroker" : false,
        # reference.conf @ jar:file:/C:/Users/XXXXX/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/net.corda/corda-node/3.1-corda/d885cb735f9d9e70dc630587cc5df98c9740f8df/corda-node-3.1-corda.jar!/reference.conf: 28
        "useSsl" : false
    },
    # hardcoded value
    "rpcUsers" : [
        # hardcoded value
        {
            # hardcoded value
            "password" : "test",
            # hardcoded value
            "permissions" : [
                # hardcoded value
                "ALL",
                # hardcoded value
                "InvokeRpc.nodeInfo",
                # hardcoded value
                "InvokeRpc.networkMapFeed",
                # hardcoded value
                "InvokeRpc.networkMapSnapshot",
                # hardcoded value
                "InvokeRpc.notaryIdentities",
                # hardcoded value
                "InvokeRpc.stateMachinesFeed",
                # hardcoded value
                "InvokeRpc.stateMachineRecordedTransactionMappingFeed",
                # hardcoded value
                "InvokeRpc.nodeInfoFromParty",
                # hardcoded value
                "InvokeRpc.internalVerifiedTransactionsFeed",
                # hardcoded value
                "InvokeRpc.vaultQueryBy",
                # hardcoded value
                "InvokeRpc.vaultTrackBy",
                # hardcoded value
                "InvokeRpc.registeredFlows"
            ],
            # hardcoded value
            "username" : "user1"
        }
    ],
    # reference.conf @ jar:file:/C:/Users/XXXXX/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/net.corda/corda-node/3.1-corda/d885cb735f9d9e70dc630587cc5df98c9740f8df/corda-node-3.1-corda.jar!/reference.conf: 5
    "trustStorePassword" : "trustpass",
    # hardcoded value
    "useTestClock" : false,
    # hardcoded value
    "verifierType" : "InMemory",
    # hardcoded value
    "webAddress" : "localhost:10008"
}
 {}
...
```

I did not know how the hardcoded values had been created. I could not connect to the webPort(10007 and 10010) that I set, but the hardcoded ports(10008 and 10011) were accessible. The values of the 2 parties were correct but the location of Notary was Zurich. It was supposed to be London.

And I tried to create IOU but failed. Here is error message:

```
(ExampleApi.kt:85) api.ExampleApi.createIOU - Failed requirement. {}
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed requirement.
```

Does anyone know how to solve the problem?

Comment: Could you reformat this question? It is hard to read with the big chunk of logs and inline error messages.

Comment: OK, I will post the question again.

Comment: What? Don't post a duplicate. [Edit] this one.

Answer (score 0):

The configuration of the `deployNodes` task is only used when running nodes from the command line (using `gradlew deployNodes`).

When running nodes via IntelliJ, the node driver is used instead (e.g. https://github.com/corda/cordapp-example/blob/release-V3/java-source/src/test/java/com/example/NodeDriver.java).

You configure the node driver using a `DriverParameters` object. The `DriverParameters` object has a `withPortAllocation` method that allows you to control how the nodes' ports are allocated.